# How to find partial string match in tuple list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples

```py
mylist = [(100, 'Unknown'), ('Unknown Player', 'BBB'), (20, 90), (40, 'DDD')]
```

I want to return a list of tuples that contains the word `Unknown`

I tried:

```py
matches = [x for x in mylist if 'Unknown' in x]
```

but that will return: `(100,'Unknown)`

I want to return: `[(100, 'Unknown'), ('Unknown Player', 'BBB')]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to search for 'Unknown' in both the elements of the tuple, not just the whole tuple.

```
matches = [x for x in mylist if (isinstance(x[0], str) and 'Unknown' in x[0]) or (isinstance(x[1], str) and 'Unknown' in x[1])]
```

You can separate it into a function:

```
def contains_unknown(a):
    return isinstance(a, str) and 'Unknown' in a

matches = [x for x in mylist if contains_unknown(x[0]) or contains_unknown(x[1])]
```

For tuples of any length, you can use builtin iterator functions to write

```
matches = [x for x in mylist if any(map(contains_unknown, x))]
```

or even

```
matches = filter(lambda x: any(map(contains_unknown, x)), mylist)
```

This of course works for tuples only of length 2.

The way this works: `map` applies `contains_unknown` to each element in `x`, returning an iterable of boolean values. `any` then returns whether any of those boolean values is True. If you opt to use `filter`, that then filters only the elements from mylist that satisfy that condition. Beware that `filter` returns a `filter` object, which is an iterable but not a list. You may want to apply `list` to it to use it as one.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
matches = [x for x in mylist if any(['Unknown' in str(y) for y in x])]

print(matches)

[(100, 'Unknown'), ('Unknown Player', 'BBB')]
```

Comment: This is good, but if one of the items is a class type which contains `Unknown` in its name will also be returned. For example lets say you define the class `UnknownClass` and your items are `[('asd', 'Unknown'), (UnknownClass, 5)]` this will return `[('asd', 'Unknown'), (__main__.UnknownClass, 5)]`. I don't know if this is accepted in his questions but it is something to take in count